# How to target react components in JSX using CSS media queries

Tags: reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries, gatsby

I am creating a blog using Gatsby, and for simplicity's sake, I have a main content component and a blog posting archive component as a second column to the right of the main content component. How do I target the archive component to make it "display: none" when using a CSS media query for mobile screen sizes?

For example, here is a snippet of layout.js:

```
const MainLayout = styled.main`
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  footer {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    a {
      color: red;
    }
  }
`;

const Layout = ({ children }) => (
  <StaticQuery
    query={graphql`
      query SiteTitleQuery {
        site {
          siteMetadata {
            title
          }
        }
      }
    `}
    render={data => (
      <div>
        <Header siteTitle={data.site.siteMetadata.title} />
        <MainLayout>
          <div>{children}</div>

          <Archive />

          <footer>
            © {new Date().getFullYear()} / Built by Michael Henry with
            {` `}
            <a href="https://www.gatsbyjs.org">Gatsby</a>
          </footer>
        </MainLayout>
      </div>
    )}
  />
);
```

If I select the `<Archive>` component in a media query like this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  Archive {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Nothing happens. If I wrap the `<Archive>` component with a `<div>` like so:

```
<div className="noMobile">
  <Archive />
</div>
```

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .noMobile {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I can make the archive component disappear, but the `<footer>` is now at the top of the page in the same column to the right in which the archive component was. I think it may have something to do with my grid layout, but I cannot figure it out. How do I select the grid layout to change within this media query if it is in a styled component (`<MainLayout>`)?

Thanks

Comment: Inside Media Query target a class where in you will hide that particular element , it will be great if you elaborate your question with a example or code you have tried so that suggestions will be specific to your implementation

Comment: If you want to footer to stay still, give it an explicit position in the grid, i.e `footer { grid-column: 1 / 2 }`

Comment: @DerekNguyen - thank you so much, that worked like a charm!